# Facebook Open Graph - Can get friend_lists but can't get members?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook-graph-api, fb-graph

I'm using Fb_graph gem on a RoR app.  I have setup Facebook login, and everything seems to be working fine.

I'm in the rails console and was exploring the API after having authenticated with a user.

I can do

```
user.friend_lists.first
=> #<FbGraph::FriendList:0x007fed1fad1420 @identifier ...>

user.friend_lists.first.name
=> "work"
```

Everything seems to be fine.  But when I try:

```
user.friend_lists.first.members
=> []
```

Even when I try

```
user.friends
=> []
```

I expect to get an array of friends but am getting an empty array instead.  I thought it was a permissions thing at first, but on the FB docs it says read_friendlists is the same permission scope that enables .friend_lists and .members of those lists, and since I'm getting a valid response from .friend_lists I know my permissioning is correct.

What am I doing wrong?  Why can't I get the members of a friendlist or even just call .friends?  Does it have to do with permissioning I've setup with my facebook account (as a user)?

Thanks very much for any help-

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yep this is gone with Graph v2.0.
Read FB's update, you cannot see user's friends anymore unless they are using your App, so by same spirit you'll not be able to see members in the friendlist.